# Can we end other user's Session?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Admin and I want to give a feature where Admin can end other user's session. Is this really possible? I know sessions are stored individually and normally nobody would do what I want but is this really possible? If yes, then how?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the Admin session to write a boolean variabile (e.g. ResetSessions=true) in the Application context, that each User session would read and call a Reset method if necessary.

```
// Admin
Application["ResetSessions"] = true;

// User
if (Convert.ToBoolean(Application["ResetSessions"]))
{
   ... reset session ...
}
```

Comment: You could use the Admin session to write an int variable to the application context identifying *which* session should end.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a ApplicationSession which hold a list of UserId's, every time the user loads a page check if the userId is in that list, if they are then logged them out.